# Android: Launch intent and send key

Tags: android, key-events

How can I send a key event to an Activity I just started?

I figured for sending I can use:

```
Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyCode);
```

But it gives me (when running on UI thread or in new thread):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: This method can not be called from the
>   main application thread

On which thread do I have to call `sendKeyDownUpSync()`?

Here is how I launch the activity:

```
public void openWhatsappConversation(String whatsappid) {
    whatsappid = "4917012345678@s.whatsapp.net";

    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.Data._ID },
            ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 + "=?",
            new String[] { whatsappid }, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    Intent whatsapp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/"
                    + c.getString(0)));

    whatsapp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "whatsapp");//

    c.close();

    if (whatsapp != null) {

        startActivity(whatsapp);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        // download for example after dialog
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.whatsapp");
        Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    }

}
```

Requires permission: android.permission.READ_CONTACTS

Comment: you can send by giving a different meaning to each key as a string. I mean ESC = "0", ENTER = "1" then use putExtraString(); and at the other activity getExtraString().

Comment: I cannot change the other activity. That's why I want to send a key event (just as if the user entered text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this site someone solved this problem (sending key events to an external activity):
http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/04/injecting-events-programatically-on-android/#.Ui81ddyg2f0

In short:
Using Android API (official and internal) the OS forbids sending key events to activities of other apps.
However, you can do it at Linux OS level. For this to work, you will need root access, though.

Answer (score -1):

```
// try this
public void openWhatsappConversation(String whatsappid) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                 whatsappid = "4917012345678@s.whatsapp.net";

                    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                            new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.Data._ID },
                            ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 + "=?",
                            new String[] { whatsappid }, null);
                    c.moveToFirst();

                    Intent whatsapp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/"
                                    + c.getString(0)));

                    whatsapp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "whatsapp");//

                    c.close();

                    if (whatsapp != null) {

                        startActivity(whatsapp);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        // download for example after dialog
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.whatsapp");
                        Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    }

                }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Launching the intent is not the problem. This code works. The key issue is how to send a key event to the launched activity.